# Icinga2 does not start because he could not load library "db_ido_mysql"

Tags: icinga2

Here is the Error:

```
root@taurus:/etc/icinga2/features-available# service icinga2 checkconfig
* checking Icinga2 configuration
information/cli: Icinga application loader (version: r2.7.2-1)
information/cli: Loading configuration file(s).
critical/config: Error: Error while evaluating expression: Could not load library 'libdb_ido_mysql.so.2.7.2': libdb_ido_mysql.so.2.7.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Location: in /etc/icinga2/features-enabled/ido-mysql.conf: 6:1-6:22
/etc/icinga2/features-enabled/ido-mysql.conf(4): */
/etc/icinga2/features-enabled/ido-mysql.conf(5):
/etc/icinga2/features-enabled/ido-mysql.conf(6): library "db_ido_mysql"
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/etc/icinga2/features-enabled/ido-mysql.conf(7):
/etc/icinga2/features-enabled/ido-mysql.conf(8): object IdoMysqlConnection "ido-mysql" {

* checking Icinga2 configuration. Check '/var/log/icinga2/startup.log' for details.


root@taurus:/etc/icinga2/features-available# icinga2 feature list
Disabled features: command compatlog debuglog gelf graphite influxdb livestatus opentsdb perfdata statusdata syslog
Enabled features: api checker ido-mysql ido-pgsql mainlog notification
```

Does anybody know what i did wrong during the installation?
there were no problems, i dont get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use Icingaweb2 with your Icinga2 installation? Then you have to install the

```
icinga2-ido-mysql
```

Package for your distribution and configure it. [Here](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/02-getting-started/) you can find a step by step instruction on how to install and configure it. If not, disable the following features:

```
ido-mysql ido-pgsql
```

Regards,
Jan